# In Eclipse Oracle Weblogic Server does not appear in the New Server window

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, weblogic

I'm trying to add a new server in `Eclipse` and the `Oracle Weblogic Server` does not appear in the server type list. I've installed the `Oracle WebLogic Server Tools` from the `Eclipse Marketplace`.

The `New Server` window looks like this:

[image]

`Eclipse`:
Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0)
Build id: 20200615-1200

`Plugin`: 17.3.0.201903121357

And here's the Workspace log:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:864)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1015)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1845)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1838)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1781)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1743)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1665)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Registry Directory not available: c:\Program Files\eclipse\jee-latest-released\eclipse\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry.
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.getProfileMap(LazyProfileRegistry.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.getProfileMap(LazyProfileRegistry.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.containsProfile(LazyProfileRegistry.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.ProfilePreferences.containsProfile(ProfilePreferences.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.ProfilePreferences.load(ProfilePreferences.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.getNode(RootPreferences.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.node(RootPreferences.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.getSharedPreferences(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.restoreRepositories(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.basicGetRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeMetadataRepository(RepositoryListener.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:843)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:835)
    ... 14 more
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.join(JobManager.java:914)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.InternalJob.join(InternalJob.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job.join(Job.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileInfoReader.waitOnSelf(FileInfoReader.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileInfoReader.getRemoteFiles(FileInfoReader.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileInfoReader.getRemoteFile(FileInfoReader.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileInfoReader.getLastModified(FileInfoReader.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.getLastModified(RepositoryTransport.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingTransport.delegateGetLastModified(CachingTransport.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingTransport.getLastModified(CachingTransport.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.createCache(CacheManager.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.getLocalFile(SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.load(SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.load(SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:775)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Artifact.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.loadRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.loadRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.CompositeArtifactRepository.load(CompositeArtifactRepository.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.CompositeArtifactRepository.addChild(CompositeArtifactRepository.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.CompositeArtifactRepository.<init>(CompositeArtifactRepository.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.CompositeArtifactRepositoryFactory.load(CompositeArtifactRepositoryFactory.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:775)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Artifact.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.loadRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.loadRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.catalog.MarketplaceCatalog.lambda$12(MarketplaceCatalog.java:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the log file, your **Eclipse installation was broken**:

```
Registry Directory not available: c:\Program Files\eclipse\jee-latest-released\eclipse\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry.
```

The missing p2 profile **prevented the installation** and uninstallation of plugins (the profile is needed to compute whether something can be installed and if so, which so-called installation units of which version have to be installed).

Make sure that the Eclipse installation directory is writable (in Windows everything in `c:\Program Files\` is not writable for a normal user by default) and do not delete the p2 directory.

When the installation is that broken, the only solution is to **install Eclipse again**. It might be that importing of existing plugins from the old installation via ***File > Import: Install > From existing Installation*** will not work either in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Eclipse solves the problem.

*Worth noting that the workspaces are still usable but You'll need to reinstall all plugins.*

Comment: Which Eclipse version and which plugins in which version did you have exactly before and after?

Comment: Eclipse:
Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0)
Build id: 20200615-1200

Plugin:
17.3.0.201903121357

In both cases.

Comment: How can you know that since you already reinstalled Eclipse? It does not sound plausible to me that the same thing behaves now differently. What exactly has changed by reinstalling Eclipse?

Comment: I have the old and the new Eclipse in front of me and the Eclipse version is the same at both but it seems like the old one does not have the Plugin installed even after i run the plugin installer and restart Eclipse.

Comment: Maybe there are hints in the log why it was not installed.

Comment: I've added the workspace log to the end of the question's description.